# Looking for way to store, get, partially update few relatively small JSON documents which has different unique types

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an app with many individualistic features which behavior is controlled by settings.
Let's say these are a few utility services with the following settings that are historically stored in separate JSON files.
Property values can be bools, integers, doubles, and also some complex types such as lists of JSON objects:

```
LightningSettings: {
  "featureVisibleInUI": true,
  "masterSwitchEnabled": true, 
  "sectionAOn": true,
  "sectionBOn": false,   
  "dimmerValue": 0.61,
  "alertRecipients" : ["owner@mail.com", "tech@mail.com"]
  "routineRecipients" : ["owner@mail.com", ...] (~0...1k recipents)     
}

HeatingSettings: {
  "featureVisibleInUI": true,
  "autoMode": true,   
  "turnOffValue": 22,   
  "maxPowerAllowed": 0.6,
  "alertRecipients" : null
}

VentilationSettings: {
"featureVisibleInUI": false,
"developmentMode": "true",
"autoMode": true
"humidityTreshlod": 0.75,
"cO2ppmTreshold": 1300
}
```

Settings are managed through WebformsUI by users to allow control of the service execution flow.
In the past, there was a separate web form for every feature setting manipulation. File content was deserialized to model and fed to asp-net MVC web form. Adding new settings was quick, by just adding new properties to the ViewModel/dtomodel and Html. Optimistic concurrency control was used to reject file overwrites if the file was updated by someone else.
Now things are quite changed.
Recently Admin UI panel was introduced with control switches for featureVisibleInUI. So to render UI form, all setting files should be to show the state for all switches. Updating it also is pain. Should fetch file again change prop and save back + check file version if there was not any other write between.

So independent file approach is not serious anymore, because a mix from many files(Projection) is required to render the required UI form.
Looks like every setting entity can be stored as independent in some kind of DB.
For example in azure table storage: Partition key = FeatureID , Rowkey= propertyName
then value + additional service fields if necessary. In this approach, problems could cause complex types such as lists that can exceed the 64 kb cell limit.
Another challenge is to construct LightningSettings or HeatingSettings objects from individual table entities.

Another approach could be to use some NoSQL DB and store each feature settings as a document, then it would be easier to store complex types, and constructing back to the required object can be simpler.
Just looking for a solution for a way to store these types in a better way than a many separate files to be able to get all required settings by one request from db instead of making a parallel request to read a many files.

Comment: Apparently, you already know the solution: use a database which supports JSON documents. Recommending a specific one is beyond the scope of this site, so what's your expectation for an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Your options are really use a database with JSON support, with the option of combining all the separate files into one big file or not. This lets everything work more or less the same and wouldn't be too hard to add in depending on how data access is inside the application. As for which one to pick, the one you know the most about is the correct answer.

The other option would be to blow out your JSON structure to a full on relational database. This approach has mostly downsides so I wouldn't recommend it unless you have a lot of experience doing something like this or already have a relational database you can leverage.